# adding -pg only if make debug specified

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

I am new to makefile, I am trying to add a make debug mode.

I have the following:

```
CXXFLAGS=-Wall -c

debug: $(EXECUTABLE)
     CXXFLAGS+=-pg

all:
....
```

for some reason it assigns it and when I put make debug it give me

```
CXXFLAGS+=-pg
/bin/sh: CXXFLAGS+=-pg: not found
make: *** [debug] Error 127
```

Is there any way to do and avoid writing the entire all command again in the debug except with -pg flags?

I tried to remove debug: target 
and CXXFLAGS was concatenated with -pg flags successfully

Comment: You may want to install `remake` (there should be a package of that name) and use `remake -x` to debug such issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using gnumake, just add:

```
debug: CXXFLAGS += -pg
debug: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

Note that it is typical to define `all` first so that it is the default.  If the rules for `debug` appear before `all` in the Makefile, `debug` becomes the default (if it is first).

Comment: perfect advice :)
1 more question is there a way to force it to compile again without make clean ?
e.g. If Im doing make debug its compiling with -pg flags but if then I want a regular make I am not able to do it unless I make clean first and then make

Comment: `make clean` is probably necessary.  I am not aware of a reliable way to force a rebuild with new flags other than `debug: clean $(EXECUTABLE)`

Answer (score 0):

All tab-indented lines below a target are piped directly to shell subprocesses, but your CXXFLAGS line is using Makefile syntax, not valid shell syntax.

Worse, even if you used shell syntax, setting the variable wouldn't carry over to lines executed under a different target; they would only affect shell commands under the same target, and then, only if all the lines are joined with `\` escape characters.

Make will read the values from environment variables, so you could set the environment variable as you run make, e.g. (Bourne-family shells):

```
myprompt$ CXXFLAGS=" -pg $CXXFLAGS" make
```